# How can I disable ARCore logs for Android?

Tags: android, bash, arcore

ArCore spams each frame the following error before it detects surfaces (trackables)

```
=== Source Location Trace: ===
third_party/arcore/ar/perception/feature_track_ml_depth_provider_utils.cc:402
third_party/arcore/ar/perception/feature_track_ml_depth_provider.cc:209
E0000 00:00:1675437554.648981   30783 motion_tracking_context.cc:1879] NOT_FOUND: Not able to find any depth measurements on feature measurements at timestamp 28971862451376
```

or

> E0000 00:00:1675437708.212223   30553 hit_test.cc:428] INTERNAL: No
> point hit.

How can I disable such logs?

Answer (score 0):

You must follow these steps to disable ARCore API call logging:

Open the AR experience in your app so that there is an active ARCore session running. Your app must be in AR mode to receive the broadcast that disables logging. The AR camera preview images should be visible on the device screen.

Then use the following [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) command to disable call logging for your app:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.google.ar.core.DISABLE_API_CALL_LOGGING
```